# Github as an Online External Storage

Tags: github, online-storage

Does *Github* serves as an online external drive? How much available space storage if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the intended purpose of github. It's intended for management/perusal of software source-code (and related assets).

Please also see this article: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

For standard online storage, I would look at Dropbox, SkyDrive, Google Drive, Amazon S3, or an online backup solution.

Comment: For example, I save projects at desktop and I pushed it onto the _Github_, does the project still existed even if I turn off my PC but the project that I pushed to Github website still exist?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta, the project you hosted on Gitbhub is stored on Github's online servers, so no matter if your computer is turned off or not, the project will still be available, from your or any other computer in the world.

Comment: Yes, the project will still exist. Yet I would advice learning about github and its intentions before using it. For example, are you aware that its repositories are completely *public* (visible by anyone) unless you purchase a plan allowing private repositories?